# Axios Incoming Readable stream randomly closes without triggering the 'close' event and it hangs in Node

Tags: node.js

I have the scenario where I want to download a large file from a Source and process it 1000th chunk at a time (just as an example).

The problem is that sometimes the Source closes the connection and it doesn't trigger the 'close' event of the downloadResponse.data which is Readable stream THUS leaving the app hanging.

I have made the following:

```
async processData(readableStream: Readable, totalFileSize: number) {
    let chunks = [];
    let totalChunksSizeRead = 0;
    let totalBytesConsumed = 0;

    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {

      readableStream.on('close', async () => {
        console.log('Stream has closed');
        if (totalBytesConsumed === totalFileSize ) {
          resolve('Successful');
        } else {
          reject('Failed');
        }
      }).on('data', async (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
        totalChunksSizeRead += chunk.length;
        if (chunks.length === 1000 ) {
      
          readableStream.pause();

          doSomethingWithTheData(chunks);
          
          // and move to the next chunks

          readableStream.resume();
      
        } else if (totalChunksSizeRead + totalBytesConsumed === totalFileSize) {
      
          doSomethingWithTheData(chunks); // then it triggers the close event when finishing

        }
      }).on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });

    });

}

async main(url: string, totalFileSize: number) {
    const downloadResponse = await axios.get(url) // downloadResponse.data is a Readable stream
    const response = await this.processData(downloadResponse.data, totalFileSize);
    return response;
}
```

Am I missing something or is there a way to handle the scenario when the source randomly aborts the connection?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add the `timeout` option. `const downloadResponse = await axios.get(ur, {timeout: 5000})`. When Socket hang up you'll receive an `ETIMEOUT` error.

Comment: Hi @lx1412, after doing some further testing, it still gets stuck and doesn't trigger the close event - leaving it hanging.
What I find is that if I add a log every time 'data' is triggered it finishes successfully, otherwise it gets stuck randomly. Would really appreciate the help because I ran out of ideas